# Mapquest in Qgis, why the blur?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, qgis-openlayers-plugin, mapquest

I'm trying to do a simple map in Qgis using mapquest has background.
I have read [that](http://www.3liz.com/blog/rldhont/index.php?post/2012/07/17/OpenStreetMap-Tiles-in-QGIS) and followed the scale values but even while using those, I get some bad blur on my map.
I can't figure out to do take it away.
I just wanted a simple base map for my map but it seems it's not so easy to find, i thought mapquest could be the one but ... doesn't work well :/
[image: bury text]

Answer (score 1):

The current version of openlayers plugin has solved the blur effect in a better way than the blogpost did.

Changing CRS to EPSG:3857 might also improve the picture.